# How to make multiple changes to contents in a list with regard to their types?

Tags: python, python-3.x

say i have a list `['GBP', 31, 'PIT', 25, ['Football]]` but I would like to modify it so that all integers are 7 less than original and all lists are converted to the string `'Football'`. I am not really sure how to let python scan through every item in the list, determine their type, and make corresponding changes. I tried something like

```
for x in the_list:
  if type(x) == ......:
    x = .....
```

but it does not really work...

Comment: that   ['Football]     should be     ['Football']

Comment: The code in your question is not helpful. Please take a look at this article: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Also you should be able to fix your question directly instead of posting a correction in comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `isinstance()`:

```
the_list = ['GBP', 31, 'PIT', 25, ['Football']]

for i, x in enumerate(the_list):
    if isinstance(x, list):
        the_list[i] = 'Football'
    elif isinstance(x, int):
        the_list[i] = x -7

the_list

['GBP', 24, 'PIT', 18, 'Football']
```

Answer (score 1):

For the general case, you can define a conversion dictionary for types:

```
d = {
int:lambda x: x-7,
list:lambda x: x[0] 
}

my_list = ['GBP', 31, 'PIT', 25, ['Football']]

new_list = [d.get(type(item), lambda x: x)(item) for item in my_list]
print(new_list) # ['GBP', 24, 'PIT', 18, 'Football']
```

This approach allows you to flexibly configure conversions and keeps them compact.

Comment: But this approach loses the flexibility of supporting sub-classes.

Comment: What if the list contains some other types of data(like tuples, sets etc.)... I want to make those items (type not listed in the dictionary) to remain the same.... I think the code you proposed does not actually work under this situation...

Comment: @PeterJiang, for tuples, sets etc ... the code works exactly you described - those items will remain the same - the `d.get(type(item), lambda x: x)` part guarantees such a behavior. By the way, you can see that it works in the provided example for the strings `'GBP'` and `'PIT'`, and you can easily check it for other cases.

Comment: So, if you want to keep a type untochable, you just don't mention it in the dictionary. But if you intend to use a lot of subclasses, this approach becomes not so flexible, as @SethMMorton rightly noted